# tach and gas gauge plus lock thru remote not working properly

Tags: fuse

my honda city 2018 just got rewired (signal cheek light) due to rat infestation. after the repair, i didnt noticed that the wire (positive & negative) touches each other, as a result, the fuse for signal/hazard was busted. i already replaced the fuse and the signal works perfectly. but after this, the tachometer and gas gauge are not returning to zero when i turn off the engine, they just stocked where there was then the engine and running. and i also noticed that when i trying to lock the car thru its remote, its not working. and also the trunk is not opening when im trying to open it thru the car's remote.

i hope you can help me with this. thanks!!## Heading ##

Comment: Are you sure that you re-joined the same wire to the same wire? A common error...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you didn't do the work on the vehicle, take it back to where you got the work done and have them fix the issues. You've already paid for it to be done and they didn't do it. I'm not sure how we can help you over the internet, as I don't see a specific issue with enough information to be able to form a coherent answer.